# How to add an app to teams with any site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-teams

I added an app to teams but I didn't used a default SharePoint site for a team in Microsoft Teams. I have to use external site. How can I use external site for a specific App in Microsoft Teams?